# Wordpress site not loading css styles on url but loading on preview after migration

Tags: css, wordpress

I recently migrated a site over using backup guard plugin

Click [here](http://www.staging.willbrowndesigns.com.au/) to see what is supposed to look like.

Click [here](http://www.nbch.net.au/) to see where i migrated it to.

The css doesn't look like it's loading on the live site (nbch.net.au) but it does show when i preview from the backend.

Anyone point me in the right direction, Im using the Divi theme which is all up to date

please let me know if anymore info is needed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Weirdly as well when i deactivate or reactivate all the plugins it loads the pages fine then once i refresh the css isn't loaded

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question. Nobody has to review your sites to find out what's going on.

Comment: This is most likely related to caching, either site caching, browser caching or both. When you are logged in, Wordpress shouldn't serve you any cached files, browser cache may still occur. To circumvent browser cache, view the site in a browser you seldom use (one that hasn't cached any recent versions of site files), or view the site in an incognito (`Shift+Crtl+N`) or using the "Guest" user for logged in chrome browsers.
You can also negate browser cache if you have the browser IDE (DevTools) open and the setting to "disable cache" (under the "Network" heading) checked

Comment: Thanks for that but still seems to be not loading properly, after some more investigating when i resize the browser to mobile it gets the styling back??

Answer (score 1):

Seemed like it was setting within divi that was causing the problem

press CLEAR from Static CSS File Generation from the Builder options and check after that.

If the issue is still present, DISABLE it and clear the browser's cache after that or check from Chrome Incognito mode or New Private Window from Mozilla Firefox.